# (Shopify) Error: Missing {{content_for_layout}} in the body section of the template

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, shopify-template, storefront, shopify-liquid

I removed **"main"** section with **"{{content_for_layout}}"** in **theme.liquid**:

```html
<main role="main">
  {{ content_for_layout }}
</main>
```

Then, I got this error as shown below:

[image]

It seems like it's impossible to remove it but I really want to remove it. Are there any ways to remove it? and it's also OK to get the same effect of removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment it out as shown below:

```html
{% comment %}  
<main role="main">
  {{ content_for_layout }}
</main>
{% endcomment %}
```

In addition, you can use **style="display: none"** in **the opening main tag**:

```html
<main role="main" style="display:none">
  {{ content_for_layout }}
</main>
```